# Drag and drop not smooth while dragging view

Tags: android, kotlin, drag-and-drop

I have an application where i need to drag the view smoothly and drop it anytime , but it is not smooth at all , i have set up code to do that but not really smooth , i appreciate any help , Thank you

- This is my code

```
 
 clMain.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
            if(event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                dx = view.x - event.rawX
                dy = view.y - event.rawY
            }
            if(event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                clearImg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                view.animate()
                    .x(event.rawX + dx)
                    .y(event.rawY + dy)
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start()
            }
            if(event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(areViewsTouching()){
                    clMain.visibility = View.GONE
                    clearImg.visibility = View.GONE
                    saveState(this,false)
                } else {
                    clearImg.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
            super.onTouchEvent(event)

        }
```

Comment: Your `OnTouchListener` is firing for multiple events, so you keep restarting the drag. You only want to start the drag on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: @MikeM. i also used onLongClickListener but the same thing , i actually use onLongClickListener , i forgot to remove the onTouchListener ,  i updated the code

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that you're kind of mixing two different ways to drag `View`s: the framework's drag-and-drop API, and doing it manually. If you're going to be updating the `x` and `y` directly yourself, you don't want to use `startDrag()` and its listener. You can just do the updates from the `OnTouchListener`, for `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, etc.

Comment: @MikeM. i have a piece code which works pretty fine and drag and drop view smoothly with onTouchListener alone , the issue is that my view has a transformation ( if i click on view which is circular , it morphs into rectangle ) , now the issue with this when i drop the view , onClickListener is triggered as well .. that's why i switched to drag listener to avoid this issue , this is the view https://www.youtube.com/shorts/vXl3lSZzDDg

Comment: Sounds like you might not be figuring the correct return value in the `OnTouchListener`. After a drag ends, you need to consume the `ACTION_UP` event, otherwise the click will fire.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for your reply , i have actually update the code which i use for the onTouchListener alone , can you please take a look and suggest a solution , appreciate your help

Comment: @MikeM. the transformation happens only when  i set the view onClickListener , onTouchListener is used to drag and drop view , but for some reason when done dragging and dropping afterwards , onClickListener is triggered

Comment: Actually, no, you're calling the `Activity`'s `onTouchEvent()` method, which is definitely not what you want to do. There is no `super` method to call in the `OnTouchListener` interface. I'm still not quite sure of the exact behavior you're wanting, but I'll try to find or put together an example here in a little bit.

Comment: OK, here's a quick example that starts the drag on a long click, and does not fire the `OnClickListener` after a drag: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EfruL5MtJvQmppMP4rOL9gxTZEdvA12z/view?usp=share_link. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nLcS.gif.

Comment: @MikeM. Did the job , Thank you mate for the help , i appreciate your help and time